# How To Enable CORS For TinyMCE Hyperlink Dialog Box

Tags: javascript, tinymce, cors, django-tinymce

I have a requirement where I need to make a cross domain request to add a hyperlink for a TinyMCE text. This opens a dialog box which has the CORS url. The problem is I cant figure out how to enable CORS for TinyMCE plugin. Any Suggestions? Thanks In Advance

Comment: this shoukld be possible, can you tell me how this gets enabled for a regular page (i guess i will be able to tell you what you will need to do to enable it for the tinymce editor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this](http://enable-cors.org/) out for more information about CORS.

Basically you can't do much from the client, it has to be enabled by the server. More in detail, some specific headers have to be added. If you have access to the server-side files it shouldn't be hard to enable it yourself.

If you're using PHP everything can be done within a single line of code:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```